# Visual Studio CPP No Entry

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I'm writing a cpp app for some while now. A few hours into the day made a small change did a build to test it and to my surprise , the build executed and nothing happened , it didn't stop executing it had a process running.
so I stopped it. and this is what I have tried.

Restrating my PC- Same Result

Making a breakpoint after the entry point. - Same Result

breakpoint didn't even hit which makes me think that the entry point just does not work.

Making a syntax error - it didn't compile and didn't run
which means my program did compile and did run before.

Completly undoing everything I did after the last running build - Same Result. it worked before but i guess not anymore

Changing my entry point from WinMain to `int main()` -
cmd window was created but no signs of code executing.

Doing std::cout on the first line(with cmd window) - Same Result

The only thing that worked was  commenting the whole file with the entry point and just writing :

```
    #include <iostream>
int main() {
    int i;
    std::cout << "hello";
    std::cin >> i;
}
```

Anyone knows what can make such a weird behavier ?

Comment: at a guess an infinite loop in a static initialiser. We need a [mcve]. Have you tried debugging and hitting pause when the program hangs?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you very much you were right. infinite loop in a static initialiser. Just by hitting pause it took me a minute to debug the problem.
it was an unexpected behavier from the debugging system it got itself into an infinite loop of error dispatching somehow.
maybe make an answer so I could mark it as solved ?

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an infinite loop in some static initialisation code.

If you hit pause in the debugger it will show you where the problem lies.